# How to select Pandas DataFrame rows for a group of months with the format yyyy-mm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, date

How can I select Pandas DataFrame rows for a group of months with the format yyyy-mm and not yyyy-mm-dd?  Given the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# Create a DataFrame of rows between 2018-01-01 and 2018-12-31
rng = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=365, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng}) 

# List of lists of quarters with start/end months/years
qtrs = [[[2018, 1], [2018, 3]], [[2018, 4], [2018, 6]], [[2018, 7], [2018, 9]], [[2018, 10], [2018, 12]]]

# Create a dictionary to store each quarter of data
folders = {}
# Cycle through each of the 4 quarters in 2018 and populate the folders dictionary
for el in qtrs:
    start_yr = el[0][0]
    start_mo = el[0][1]
    end_yr =  el[1][0]
    end_mo = el[1][1]

    # How can I modify this code below????
    folders['qtr_end_'+str(end_yr)+'_'+str(end_mo)] = df[(df['Date'] >= str(start_yr)+'-'+str(start_mo)) & (df['Date'] <= str(end_yr)+'-'+str(end_mo))]
```

I receive a dictionary of DataFrames with the following keys:

```
dict_keys(['qtr_end_2018_3', 'qtr_end_2018_6', 'qtr_end_2018_9', 'qtr_end_2018_12'])
```

For example, `folders['qtr_end_2018_3']` starts with `2018-01-01` and ends with `2018-03-01` not `2018-03-31`:

```
        Date
0  2018-01-01
1  2018-01-02
2  2018-01-03
3  2018-01-04
4  2018-01-05
......
55 2018-02-25
56 2018-02-26
57 2018-02-27
58 2018-02-28
59 2018-03-01
```

My desired output is each DataFrame to include all dates from the beginning of the quarter to the end of the quarter.  For example, `folders['qtr_end_2018_3']` should start and end like this:

```
        Date
0  2018-01-01
1  2018-01-02
2  2018-01-03
3  2018-01-04
4  2018-01-05
......
85 2018-03-27
86 2018-03-28
87 2018-03-29
88 2018-03-30
89 2018-03-31
```

Is there a way that I can modify my code to achieve my desired output while maintaining my input list of start/end month/year for each quarter?

Comment: You can use `pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd` and `pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterBegin` to find the dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have to keep your **qtrs** list, using .dt might help, it's pretty straightforward. Take a look at this :

```
df[(df.Date.dt.year == 2018) & (df.Date.dt.month >= 1) & (df.Date.dt.month <= 3)]
```

Above code will subset your date based on year and month you provide.

Hope it helps, tell me if you need further details.

Comment: This is it!  I was looking for a way that would allow me to keep the same messed up flow of code that I have instead of having to redo it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?
`from datetime import date`

`qtr_start = pd.to_datetime(date(year=start_yr, month=start_mo, day=1) - pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterBegin(startingMonth=1)).date()`

`qtr_ends = pd.to_datetime(date(year=end_yr, month=end_mo, day=1) - pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd(startingMonth=1)).date()`

To get the dates in between you could use `df[(df['Date'] >= qtr_start) & (df['Date'] <= qtr_end)]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use dt.quarter in DataFrame of Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
rng = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=365, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng}) 

# Print day, month, year if you want
df['day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).day
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).month
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).year

# add quarter column for classify that you want
df['quarter'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.quarter
df.head(n=91)
```

The results:

[image]

You also can edit your code with below:

```
conditions = [
(df['quarter'] == 1),
(df['quarter'] == 2),
(df['quarter'] == 3),
(df['quarter'] == 4)]
choices = ['qtr_end_2018_3', 'qtr_end_2018_6', 'qtr_end_2018_9', 'qtr_end_2018_12']
df['q_str'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0)
print(df)
```

And run again, results below:

[image]